# Announcement tiles missing Add Item button

Tags: web-part, app-part, announcement-tiles

Why does the announcement tiles app not have a toolbar with the "add item" button like other lists? Do I need to do something to add it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to

- Edit the page and then select and edit the web part (select Web Part in the top menu and then click Web Part Properties).
- Under Toolbar Type select `Show Toolbar` and click OK.